# asp:Textbox with type=number allowing "e"

Tags: asp.net, textbox, numbers

I am currently making an asp.net webpage with a asp:TextBox field, I set the TextBox to type=number, and it is now accepting only numbers with one exception. It also accepts the letter "e". Does someone know what might cause this and how to solve it?

```
<asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" type="number" id="LotNumber" placeholder="Lotnummer" runat="server" Text="<% $RouteValue:ordernummer %>"/>
```

Comment: All number can be written in an exponential notation, so you shouldn't forbid this way of writing numbers.

Comment: @DawidFerenczy Well, as the numbers are used as ID's for the DB I'm communicating with, "e" is not very useful to get as input which is doesn't convert to the written out number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using JavaScript. Please check following code:

```
 <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" type="number" id="LotNumber" placeholder="Lotnummer" runat="server" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" Text="<% $RouteValue:ordernummer %>"/>
```

Please paste following code in  tag of your page:

```
<SCRIPT language=Javascript>

      function isNumberKey(evt)
      {
         var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
         if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
            return false;

         return true;
      }

   </SCRIPT>
```

Answer (score 1):

10^20 = 1e+20

It is a notation. I suppose that's why "e" is allowed

**EDIT:**

In your case, if you want to prevent "e", floating numbers and negative numbers, you should change your ASP Textbox like this:

```
<asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" type="text" pattern="[0-9]+" id="LotNumber" placeholder="Lotnummer" runat="server" Text="<% $RouteValue:ordernummer %>"/>
```

Comment: Makes sense, but is there any way I can prevent it from accepting "e"?

Comment: It probably accepts floatings and negative numbers too. Textbox for numbers is an HTML5 feature. If you use <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]+" /> browser will not submit the form with showing an error to the client unless the client will fill a non-negative integer.

Comment: I tried the piece of code you provided, but now it just accepts all characters instead of 0-9. So not really what I'm looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can use RegularExpressionValidator.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter only digits" ValidationExpression="\d+"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Comment: I tested your solution and it does give me an error message when I enter eg. "-" but it does not trigger on "e"...

Comment: Did you only put 'e' in the textbox ? I tested samples like 'e', '1e' etc. It is giving me same validation message.